# Playing base64 midi files in IE9

Tags: audio, internet-explorer-9, base64, midi, playback

I'm building an intranet website for a client of mine which enables him to create, edit and play midi files. Only that Playing midi files on IE9 is not as easy as I thought it would be.

In a specific situation I need to play a base64 midi file, which is stored in memory, doing so on client side only (no postback). What I have working for me in Firefox:

```
<EMBED  hidden=true autostart=true loop=1 type="audio/mid" SRC="data:audio/mid;base64,TVRoZAAAAA...">
```

Every HTML, CSS, JS solution is acceptable. Limitations - no with Java applets, must work on IE9, only client side, preferably no special plugins.

I would appreciate answers dealing with the problem and not "why would you want to that..?".

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Quicktime qualifies as a "special plugin", but I'm pretty sure it can handle MIDI files if it's set as the default media player. Try these instructions (even though they appear to apply to non-IE browsers):

1. From the Start menu, choose Default Programs.
2. Click on "Set Program Access and Computer Defaults".
3. Choose Non-Microsoft
4. Choose any browser, and choose QuickTime from the dropdown menus.
5. Click Ok or whatever is necessary to close the forms.

Your embedded MIDI file should then play with QuickTime.